# Vanishing theorems on a non-compact manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In complex geometry,  various vanishing theorems for cohomology
groups of a hermitian line bundle E over a compact complex manifold X have been found.

My question is

Is there some vanishing theorems over a **general noncompact** complex manifold exist? (Except shose on  Stein manifolds)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A complex manifold of dimension $n$ is non-compact if and only if $H^n(X,{\mathcal F})=0$ for any coherent sheaf  ${\mathcal F}$  on $X$. This is the only general vanishing result that I know of on non-compact manifolds.

But other than that, there are some other vanishing theorems on non-compact manifolds. For instance, if $X$ is $q$-complete, then $H^r(X, {\mathcal F})=0,\forall r\geq q$.

Or if $X$ is weakly $1$-complete, and $L$ is a positive line bundle on $X$, then $H^{n,q}(X,L)=0$, $\forall q\geq 1$.

In general, for a non-compact manifold, you know nothing about the cohmology groups, they can even be non-Hausdorff.

Comment: $H^{q, n}(X, L)$ or   $H^{n, q}(X, L)$  in  para3?

Comment: You're right, thank you.